# R: Reading a netCDF file as a raster

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, r-raster

I'm trying to read into R a netCDF file as a raster. The netCDF file describes mean annual temperature in the ocean as a function of longitude, latitude, and depth. I'm concerned with the surface ocean (i.e., the first level in the netCDF file) and `t_an` is the name of the variable in the netCDF file. Therefore, I use the following code:

```
MyRast <- raster("Temperature.nc", level = 1, varname = "t_an")
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In .getCRSfromGridMap4(atts) : cannot process these parts of the CRS: epsg_code=EPSG:4326
```

As you can see, the netCDF file has CRS EPSG 4326 (or WGS 84), yet the raster that is created has the following CRS:

```
+proj=longlat +lon_0=0 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257232666016
```

Any ideas how I read in the file netCDF with the correct CRS?

Comment: can you give a link to the netCDF?

Comment: Downloaded from this link https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/OC5/woa13/woa13.pl selecting netCDF as the format and 1/4º as the available grid and the file is called t00_04v2.nc under the Annual heading.

Comment: are you dead set with using netCDF?

Comment: No, not dead set. It just seemed easiest to work with (i.e., load the file and pull out the variable I want in the first level all in a single command). To give you some background: ultimately, I want to use this raster along with the extract function and a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to get the raster cells that are found in those polygons.

Comment: I've used that file before - will try to find my code (though I might not have had to deal with projections)

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate the help.

Comment: There is nothing here that shows that the CRS you are getting is not correct. What you get is extracted from the file. It is slightly different from the WGS84 ellipsoid. So the file apparently has contradictory information. If the EPSG code is correct, then use Geo-sp's suggestion.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply @RobertH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is setting the projection after you read in the data:

```
r <- raster("Temperature.nc",  varname = "t_an")
proj4string(r)=CRS("+init=EPSG:4326")
```

Comment: or `crs(r) <- "+init=EPSG:4326"`